# php cookie have quote remove

Tags: php, cookies

I try to display content from a cookie with php but it shows me with quotes.>"name"

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE['name_user']; ?>
```

What can I do to not appear quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ltrim` and `rtrim`:

```
$name = $_COOKIE['name_user']; // "name"
$name = ltrim($name, '"');     //  name"
$name = rtrim($name, '"');     //  name
echo $name;

// Everything in one line:
echo ltrim(rtrim($_COOKIE['name_user'], '"'), '"');
```

Easier solution (suggested by Fluffy):

```
echo trim($_COOKIE['name_user'], '"');
```

Comment: Yeah, sorry I just corrected a small mistake in my answer. Please accept my answer if it helped you :)

Comment: btw you can just use `trim($name, '"')` instead of rtrim + ltrim